# Override template parameters in release pipeline not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Devops in release pipeline, I am configuring variables (name of the resources to be deployed for Dev, preprod stages).Hence under override template parameters, i am specifying -accountName $(accountName) but the name as mentioned in variables (for Dev, preprod) is not accepted, instead it takes the values from template parameters json. Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use `${{ variables.accountName}}` instead `$(accountName)` in the pipeline to pass the parameters to the template. You can set the variable `system.debug` as true to check the full log of the pipeline. In the last section in InitializePipeline, you can see how the resulting yaml looks. It seems that `${{ }}` is evaluated during processing the templates etc. but `$()` is evaluated later.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as well but a slightly different solution.

My sample `azure-pipelines.yml` where `flag` parameter wasn't being overridden in the template.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: var1
    type: string
  - name: var2
    type: string
  - name: bool1
    type: bool

...
omitted
...

          - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
            inputs:
              deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
              azureResourceManagerConnection: ''
              subscriptionId: ''
              action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
              resourceGroupName: rg-${{parameters.var1}}-${{parameters.var2}}
              location: ''
              templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
              csmFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/arm.json
              csmParametersFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/arm.parameters.json
              deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
              overrideParameters: >-
                -string1 ${{parameters.var1}}
                -string2 ${{parameters.var2}}
                -flag ${{parameters.bool1}}
```

The problem was with my overrideParameters block style.
I was using `>-` which removes all newlines at the end but `>` works which puts a newline at the end. Learn more [here](https://yaml-multiline.info/).